# Make 'Google' the default docstring style for ALL projects PyCharm

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, docstring

I'm aware that I can go to Settings | Tools | Python Integrated Tools | Docstrings | Docstring format | Google, but this only sets the the docstring format for the current project (as indicated by the heading 'for current project' in the window). I'm looking for a way to change the default, so that all of my projects utilize the google docstring format by default.

JetBrain's [own documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-tools-python-integrated-tools.html) makes no mention of how to accomplish this as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of this writing, it is not possible. Several tickets have been submitted over the past several years requesting this feature, presumably it is being worked on.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-33833

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20243

In the short run, if you need to convert previous projects from the default, you can find the setting is stored in the ".idea/MYPROJECT.iml" file:

```
  <component name="PyDocumentationSettings">
    <option name="myDocStringFormat" value="Google" />
  </component>
```

By default, there is no PyDocumentationSettings component, so you'll need to add it. In Linux, you could run the following (very hackish) code in terminal to change all projects in any subdirectory:

```
new_docstring='  <component name="PyDocumentationSettings">\n    <option name="myDocStringFormat" value="Google" />\n  </component>\n</module>'
find . -type f -name '*.iml' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s|</module>|$new_docstring|g"
```

If you simply wanted to go from e.g. Numpy to Google, you might just use:

```
find . -type f -name '*.iml' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s|Numpy|Google|g"
```

Answer (score 4):

This isn't possible to do at the moment. Please submit a feature request about it to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY

EDIT:
The following ticket (mentioned below) is now in **In Progress** status https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20243.
According to **Fix versions** field, it should be implemented in 2019.3 version.